# MySQL - SUM an AS Like SUM(test1) AS test2, SUM(test2)

Tags: mysql, sum

I have got a simmelar porblem,
I want to sum "totaal_inclusief_btw" in the following Query:
Can someone help me how to fix this? Can't figure it out.

Table 1 (facturen)

```
factuur_id    factuur_datum    factuur_btw_weergave
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             2012-05-10       inclusief
2             2012-05-10       exclusief
```

Tabel 2 (factuur_regels)

```
regel_id    regel_factuur_id    regel_aantal   regel_bedrag   regel_btw
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18          1                   1              40             19
19          1                   2              40             6
20          2                   1              40             19
21          2                   2              40             6
```

**With the following Query:**

```
SELECT 
CASE    
 WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'inclusief' 
 THEN SUM(regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)
 WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'exclusief' 
 THEN SUM(((regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)/100)*(100+regel_btw))
END
AS totaal_inclusief_btw,
SUM(totaal_inclusief_btw) AS new
FROM factuur_regels
INNER JOIN facturen ON factuur_id = regel_factuur_id
GROUP BY factuur_datum
```

I get the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'totaal_inclusief_btw' in 'field list'
```

**When I leave the second SUM "SUM(totaal_inclusief_btw) AS new":**

```
SELECT 
CASE    WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'inclusief' THEN SUM(regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)
        WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'exclusief' THEN SUM(((regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)/100)*(100+regel_btw))
        END
        AS totaal_inclusief_btw

FROM factuur_regels
LEFT JOIN facturen ON factuur_id = regel_factuur_id
WHERE factuur_datum = '2012-05-10'
GROUP BY factuur_datum
```

I will get this result:

```
totaal_inclusief_btw: 
240 (this needs to be 252,4)
```

**And when I Group by "factuur_id":**

```
SELECT 
CASE    WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'inclusief' THEN SUM(regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)
        WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'exclusief' THEN SUM(((regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)/100)*(100+regel_btw))
        END
        AS totaal_inclusief_btw

FROM factuur_regels
LEFT JOIN facturen ON factuur_id = regel_factuur_id
WHERE factuur_datum = '2012-05-10'
GROUP BY factuur_id
```

I will get this result:

```
totaal_inclusief_btw: 
120
132.4
```

**I HOPE SOMEONE CAN HELP ME WITH THIS QUERY! THANK YOU**

Comment: Have you tried using a sum **around** the CASE statement (instead of inside) and grouping by factuur_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved**

It works now with the following query:

```
SELECT factuur_datum, SUM(totaal_inclusief_btw)
FROM    (
               SELECT  factuur_datum,
               CASE    WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'inclusief' THEN SUM(regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)
                            WHEN factuur_btw_weergave = 'exclusief' THEN SUM(((regel_bedrag*regel_aantal)/100)*(100+regel_btw))
                            END
                            AS totaal_inclusief_btw
               FROM factuur_regels
               LEFT JOIN facturen ON factuur_id = regel_factuur_id
               WHERE factuur_datum = '2012-05-10'
               GROUP BY factuur_id
               )q
```

This query returns: 252.4 (is correct)